# Showing what satellites can "see" in GMAT

Tags: gmat

I'm currently working on orbit modeling in GMAT and I'm interested in visualizing the satellite's visibility on the ground track. Is there a feature or tool within GMAT that allows for the representation of the satellite's line of sight or visibility on the ground track? Apologies if my terminology isn't precise—I'm seeking a method to display the areas where the satellite is in view from the ground. Any guidance on how to achieve this in GMAT would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The angle between the point below the observer, the center of the planet, and the horizon is $ \gamma=\cos^{-1}\left( \dfrac{R}{R+h} \right) $. Where $R$ is the radius of the planet, and $h$ is the altitude.